# PAYPAL - curl request

Tags: curl, paypal

Hi,

After finally and successfully have gotten an authorization token from https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token, now I need to construct a payment object.

Paypal suggests the following code:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
-H "Content-Type:application/json"
-H "Authorization:Bearer A015Mw6GQ5z3CtAUWFdzTISeW7KJcA4s0dssTXavN.N7djY"
-d '{
        "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "currency":"USD",
            "total":"12"
        },
        "description":"creating a payment"
        }],
        "payer": {
            "payment_method":"paypal"
        },
        "intent":"sale",
        "redirect_urls": {
            "cancel_url":"https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/curl?cancel=true",
            "return_url":"https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/curl?success=true"
        }
   }'
```

My PHP code is:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$token = "A015Mw6GQ5z3CtAUWFdzTISeW7KJcA4s0dssTXavN.N7djY";
$data = '{
        "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "currency":"USD",
            "total":"12"
        },
        "description":"creating a payment"
        }],
        "payer": {
            "payment_method":"paypal"
        },
        "intent":"sale",
        "redirect_urls": {
            "cancel_url":"http://myurl.com/cancel.php",
            "return_url":"http://myurl.com/return.php"
        }
   }';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Content-Type:application/json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Authorization:Bearer ".$token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($result, TRUE); // 'true' converts it to an array
print_r($json);
curl_close($ch);
```

It returns no json data. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the exact solution you might be asking for, but as a PayPal Employee, and Contributor to [PayPal PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK), I am just curious, if there is any specific reason for you to use your own implementation, instead of using the PayPal Official SDK for PHP.

If you are planning to implement multiple APIs to your website, you might want to get started with [PayPal PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK).

Here are the [samples](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/index.php), that you could view/run locally which comes packaged with SDK itself.

It has all the documentation you need to get started. Here are some important links for you:

- [Github](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK)
- [SDK Wiki](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki)
- [Installing SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Installation)
- [Making Your First Call using SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call)
- [Running Samples locally, that includes Payment APIs](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Samples)
- [API Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/)

Also, feel free to create an [issue](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues) if you run into any issues running our SDK. I should be able to quickly help you get started.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i managed to found the errors: $data was not properly json-formatted and CURLOPT_HEADER should be CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER instead

Comment: PayPal PHP SDK is deprecated